# How to clear ActiveJob queue

Tags: sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have jobs that are trying and failing repeatedly..how to I clear them?  I now have the retries count set to 0, but that doesn't help the jobs that are already queued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Sidekiq Web UI.  You can remove jobs via it.

Comment: Thanks for creating the solution and making it so easy to use!

Comment: Can i do this without the sidekiq web ui? i'd rather not install it

Comment: `require 'sidekiq/api';Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)`